# Could not install .ipa through iTunes

Tags: ios, installation, itunes, ipa

I have developed an iPad application using iOS 4.3 SDk. I tried to install the application in a device which runs on iOS 5. I could not install the ipa. It is giving an error that it is not a valid ipa. The provisioning profile is set properly. How this can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use iTunes.
You must use Xcode which is fairly easy.

1. Next to the Build and Stop buttons there is drop down menu where you can select ipHone/Ipad simulators and any connected iOS device (given it is compatible with the project)
2. Just press run (cmd+R) and it will build, load and run your device. You might need to add your device via Organizer/Devices: Select device and press "Use device for development"

I hope it helps

Comment: Distributed this app as a ad-hoc distribution. The remote device could not install the application

Comment: I haven't done ad-hoc distribution yet, but if that is what you want to do you should rephrase the question emphasising that your ad-hoc distribution doesn't work. If you want to install your app on a device you have physical access probably Xcode is the easiest option.